# Moving player on Y axis in Godot 2D

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

I'm new to Godot.
I'm trying to make my player move vertically just like when it's moving horizontally.
I've tried a couple of thoughts, but unfortunately, I couldn't move him the I want him to move.
I want to code my vertical movement in a similar way to my following horizontal movement code if possible:

```
var direction: = Vector2(
    Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left"), 0.0
)
velocity = speed * direction
velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
```

And if it's not possible, how can I code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once upon a time there were vectors. I'm not in the mood to make yet another [Introduction to Vector Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4335556/6928) or to explain [How to Work With Arbitrarily Oriented Vectors](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/160075/10408). *Perhaps you might be interested in [Math for Game Devs](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLImQaTpSAdsD88wprTConznD1OY1EfK_V).*

In this case, what you need to know is that 2D Vectors have an horizontal an a vertical component (usually called `x` and `y` respectively). And you are leaving your vertical component at zero, here:

```
var direction: = Vector2(
    Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left"), 0.0
)
```

So… Er… Don't do that. You say you want it to be like the horizontal, so something like this:

```
var direction: = Vector2(
    Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left"),
    Input.get_action_strength("move_down") - Input.get_action_strength("move_up")
)
```

*In computer graphics the vertical component in 2D often goes downwards, due to historical reasons. There are [different conventions for 3D](https://twitter.com/freyaholmer/status/1325556229410861056), but that is not the issue at hand, pun intended.*

The other lines you have already work with arbitrary vectors. You don't need to change them, nor repeat them.